# cannot access angular service from external js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

this is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="services.js"></script>
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl2">
   hello {{x}} 
 </div>
 <script>
  var app=angular.module("myApp", []);
  app.controller("myCtrl2", ['$scope','$location', function($scope, $location) {
    myService.set("world");
    $scope.x=myService.get();
  }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my services.js file:

```
    var app=angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.factory('myService', function() {
     var savedData = {}
     function set(data) {
       savedData = data;
     }main.html
     function get() {
      return savedData;
    }

    return {
      set: set,
      get: get
    }

  });
```

why doesn't I get hello world but instead chrome developers tool say: ReferenceError: myService is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to correct couple of things

1. Don't recreate a `myApp` module on html page, that will destroy old registered component of module. Instead use the existing `myApp` module created by `services.js`.

   ```
   var app=angular.module("myApp", []);
   ```

   should be

   ```
   var app=angular.module("myApp");
   ```
2. Do inject service before using it in controller.

   ```
   app.controller("myCtrl2", ['$scope','$location', 'myService', 
       function($scope, $location, myService) {
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the service into your controller.

```
app.controller("myCtrl2", ['$scope','$location', function($scope, $location,myService) {
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to inject service in controller

```
var app=angular.module("myApp", []);
 app.controller("myCtrl2", ['$scope','$location','myService', function($scope, $location,myService) {
  myService.set("world");
  $scope.x=myService.get();
}]);
```